# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name

Tags: tomcat, servlets, illegalargumentexception, servlet-mapping

When I try run my project I get error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name dispatcher
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3156)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3135)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1176)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

My `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 15):

The `<servlet-name>` of the `<servlet-mapping>` entry must be exactly the same as the `<servlet-name>` of the `<servlet>` entry.

So, in your specific case, change this line in `<servlet-mapping>` entry

```
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
```

to

```
<servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
```

Comment: Is your application up?

Comment: I copy this application from "Spring MVC: Beginner's Guide" Amuthan G

Comment: That's okay, but is it running properly on your machine now or still not getting run as per your expectation that I am asking.

Comment: In my case i had no `<servlet>`, just `<servlet-mapping>`.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name dispatcher
```

Your servlet name in the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` must be same.